# Extend a frame to two pages

Tags: beamer

I am using `beamer` to create slides for presentation. I am trying to put 4 equations with numbers from 1 to 4 in two pages. in short, how can I extend a frame to two pages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the option `allowframebreaks`; notice, however, that this deactivates overlay specifications:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Perhaps you could consider manually splitting the equations in two frames in order to keep overlays functional?

After a comment, it seems that all that is required is an overlay specification:

```
\documentclass{beamer}          

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item To evaluate the performance of the algorithm, different Evaluation metrics can be defined.\pause 
  \begin{enumerate} 
  \item<+-> $a = b+c$
  \item<.-> $h= d+k$
  \item<+> $a= c^2+d^2$ 
  \item<.> $m= h+c$ 
  \end{enumerate} 
\end{itemize} 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

After a new comment, I'd recommend using two frames and stepping the `enumi` counter:

```
\documentclass{beamer}          

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item To evaluate the performance of the algorithm, different Evaluation metrics can be defined.
  \begin{enumerate} 
  \item $a = b+c$
  \item $h= d+k$
  \end{enumerate} 
\end{itemize} 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item[]
  \begin{enumerate}
  \setcounter{enumi}{2} 
  \item $a= c^2+d^2$ 
  \item $m= h+c$ 
  \end{enumerate} 
\end{itemize} 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo , my code is like this :
\subsection{Metrics of Evaluation}
\begin{frame}{Metrics of Evaluation}

\begin{itemize}[<+->]

\item[] To evaluate the performance of the algorithm, different Evaluation metrics can be defined.

\begin{enumerate}
\item \[a = b+c\]
\item \[h=  d+k\]
\item \[a=  c^2+d^2\]
\item \[m=  h+c\] 
\end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

I want the first two equation be in the fist slide with number 1 and 2, and the next two equations be at the second slide with number 3 and 4.  [allowframebreak] it only shows the first sentence : To evaluate ....

Comment: @shahb please see my updated answer. Is it something like that (in the second example code) what you need?

Comment: I updated the code and it keeps giving this error : 
Runaway argument?
{Metrics of Evaluation} \par \begin {itemize} \par \item To evaluate \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \frame.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> ...s/miktex/defence_file/test/defence_test.tex

Comment: @shahb In my code I don't have any \par commands and also notice that I used `\frametitle`; please process my code exactly as it is.

Comment: I used your code and its working. But I want the first two equation be on a different slide something like this :
slide 1 ---->
1. a = b+c
2. h = d+k
slide 2--->
3. a= c^2+d^2 
4. m= h+c

since my equations are big, so i want to take them apart two to different pages.

Comment: @shahb answer updated. Let me know if the third code is closer to what you want.